# How can I create a home screen bookmark that opens to the correct page in the LinkedIn app?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen

I have saved a bookmark to https://www.linkedin.com/my-items/saved-posts/ to my Android home screen.

Clicking the icon opens that page in Brave.

How can I instead create a home screen bookmark that opens to the correct page in the LinkedIn app?

UPDATE:

[image: screenshot]

Given that these are my settings, and especially confused that it doesn't already work properly.

Comment: Which phone model and Android version is your question about? AFAIR Google had changed the link open behavior a few times with each Android version.

Comment: @Robert Google Pixel 3 with Android 12. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Linkedin app registers for URL schemes like, so if the URL doesn't work you can try to build URLs and replace `https://www.linkedin.com` with one of those below:

- `linkedin://thirdparty`
- `linkedin://you`
- `linkedin://profile`
- `linkedin://jobs`
- `linkedin://oneclicklogin`

For regular URLs the there are hundred of possible paths defined in `AndroidManifest.xml` of LinkedIn app. The base URL can be like in your example `https://www.linkedin.com`:

As the full path list is too long for this answer I focus on entries that include the term `saved` and `post`:

- `/my-items/saved-posts`
- `/my-items/saved-posts/`
- `/comm/my-items/saved-posts`

So the URL you tried is registered by the LinkedIn app. If it does not work this can have two reasons:

1. The used web browser does not query Android if the URL is assigned to an app and just opens itself and displays the URL. Try a different web browser. Or try an app that allows to open URLs using Intents.
2. You have permanently assigned the web browser to that URL type so Android does no longer ask where to open the URL. AFAIR the assignment can be reset in app settings.

Comment: Thanks! Visiting https://www.linkedin.com/my-items/saved-posts/ in Brave or Chrome does not open the LinkedIn app. Visiting that URL by pasting it into the Google search bar at the bottom of my home screen *does* open the correct page on the LinkedIn app. Interesting. So I need to figure out why Brave's bookmark (which I saved to the home screen where I want it) still just opens it within Brave.

Comment: I added a screenshot above.

Comment: @Ryan That screen shot just shows that the Linkedin app is allowed to open URLs, but it doesn't tell you if it is selected to open certain links.